# Cannot Build Manifest for JS with Imports

Tags: google-chrome-extension, manifest, importerror

I am a noob trying to write a a Chrome extension. My JS (converted from Python) includes imports that apparently are only allowed in modules. From what I read this must be done in background. I cannot find how to do this properly in the manifest. This is the manifest I have but don't know where to go from here:

**Edited Manifest**

**2nd edit and added JS**

```
​{
   "manifest_version": 3,

   "name": "Python Chrome Plugin",
   "description": "This extension runs Python code.",
   "version": "1.0",

   "action": {
      "default_icon": "icon.ico",
      "type": "module",
      "default_popup": "auto_select.html"
   },
   "permissions": [
      "activeTab"
   ]
}
```

JS

```
import * as requests from 'requests';
import * as json from 'json';
var json_formatted_str, obj, url;
console.log("Getting page data")
```

Since this doesn't work (import only in module error), I don't know where to go next. The documentation on building a manifest is very poor (IMO). Can someone guide me through this? TIA.

Comment: `"mode"` should be `"type"`.

Comment: Thanks. That was not clear from the documentation. I edited the manifest but have now encountered a new error. Uncaught SyntaxError: Private field '#url' must be declared in an enclosing class. I have no idea what that means. It is talking about the service_worker javascript.

Comment: Show the code that contains the error.

Comment: I edited the original post. The error is coming from the service_worker parameter.

Comment: If you still see the error about #url, show the code of auto_select.js. BTW it seems you're loading the same script both in html and in the service worker, which is a mistake. Use different scripts because these contexts are completely different.

Comment: Ah, you may have hit on the problem. Please clarify which is needed and when if the script contains imports. Thanks.

Comment: Imports is not the deciding factor, they can be used anywhere. To use them in html add the type=module attribute to your script tag. You probably don't need service worker at all.

Comment: Thanks again for the help. I again edited the manifest in the original post but I am now back to the original error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Comment: You didn't show the code...

Comment: Oops, sorry, I guess I forgot to click save after my edit.

Comment: When using the native import, module names must start with a path and end with an extension like .js or .mjs e.g. `import * as json from './json.js';`

Comment: OK, so where are those modules (directory)? Are they there automagically or do I need to download them and if so from where? This complicates the portability of my script.

Comment: I have no idea what those modules are. You can use built-in JavaScript methods instead.

Comment: I thought those were Javascript available modules. I see now they are not. I'm taking your advice and writing built-in Javascript methods instead. Thanks.